# how to use recursion to count down after counting up

Tags: c, recursion

I am trying to get my program to count down after counting up to ten. I have tried to alter the code from counting up to make it count down to no avail.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void count(int k)
{
    if (k > 0) {
        count(-k + 1);
        printf("%d", k);
    }
    else {
        if (k == 0)
        {
            printf("%d,", k);
        }
        else {
            count(k + 1);
            printf("%d,", -k);
        }
    }

}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    count(10);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: One print before recursive call, one after. This spaghetti of conditionals is unnecessary. Here is how to do it the other way around. You should be able to modify it to your needs: https://ideone.com/XnKqTi

Comment: could you explain further?

Comment: See the updated comment

Comment: @EugeneSh  _count down after counting up to ten_

Comment: @BLUEPIXY As I said "the other way around". I mean "the opposite" by it.

Comment: @DavidScarpa Is this starting from `0`? Also, does 10 duplicate? E.g `0,1,2..9,10,10,9...0` or `0,1,2..9,10,9,...,0`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple example of the recursion which does this, illustrating Eugene's comment:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void count(int n) {
    if (n > 10) {
        printf("\n");
        return;
    }

    printf("%d ", n);
    count(n+1);
    printf("%d ", n);
}

int main() {
    count(0);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

it counts up on the way into recursion and *counts down* while it exits it. Actually on the way down it only re-prints the state which it was before diving into the next level:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The function can be easy implemented if to use a static local variable inside it. For example.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void count(unsigned int n)
{
    static unsigned int m;

    printf("%u ", m);

    if (n != m)
    {
        ++m;
        count(n);
        --m;

        printf("%u ", m);
    }
}

int main( void )
{
    const unsigned int N = 10;
    unsigned int i = 0;

    do
    {
        count(i);
        putchar('\n');
    } while (i++ != N);

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
0
0 1 0
0 1 2 1 0
0 1 2 3 2 1 0
0 1 2 3 4 3 2 1 0
0 1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1 0
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
```

Within the function the static variable `m` behaves as an index in a for loop (or there will be more suitable a do-while loop).

At first it is initialized implicitly by zero (as any static variable)

```
static unsigned int m;
```

You can use the initializer explicitly if you want

```
static unsigned int m = 0;
```

then it is changed from 0 to n and afterward backward from n again to 0.

```
++m; // changing from 0 to n
count(n);
--m; // changing from n to 0
```

Comment: The static variabkle makes this more confusing than clear, I think.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It behaves as an index in a for loop changing from 0 to n and then backward from n to 0:         ++m;
        count(n);
        --m;
. So in my opinion the code is clear.